# Not able to install mint with UEFI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, uefi

In order to install Linux mint mate edition on a HP pavilion notebook, I downloaded the iso file on the official website. I created a bootable USB stick with Rufus. I shrinked the windows partition and I have a partition only for Linux. When I reboot, I can go to the boot menu. The menu is asking for an EFI file and I don't have it in my usb key. I looked in the directories of the usb key, and nothing is related to EFI. I disabled the "secure boot" and I don't have a "fast boot" option.

I'm not able to go in the Mint's install menu. Is there something to do?

Answer (score 0):

Rufus might have spoiled the image, try plain `dd if=mint.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1M` where sdX is corresponding to your flashdrive, see also `fdisk -l` or `dmesg | grep sd`

The proper EFI boot media is a FAT32 one with `EFI/BOOT/` in its topdir; you might want to read up on [EFI bootloader principles](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) if interested.  Matthew Garrett's [ISO9660 notes](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/4957.html) are hilarious and much recommended either.